# Orion Context Broker GEOLOCATION, How to deal with location not known?

Tags: fiware-orion

Regarding "position" below. I am trying to find what is the best way to define the value of "position" attribute as Location not known. I means how to represent location not known in orion database.

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "City",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Madrid",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "position",
                    "type": "geo:point",
                    "value": "LocationNotKnown"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi fgalan, if you're in, Could you possibly give me an advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the present moment (up to Orion 2.3.0) `geo:point` attribute needs a valid point as value, so thinks like `"LocationNotKnown"` will not work.

However, we have been discussing the possibility of allowing `null` or `""` as valid value for geo:point (and other similar attribute types) to mean "no location" (or "no date", in the case of DataTime). You can join the discussion [on the corresponing github issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3533) and provide your opinion there.

On the meanwhile, the recommended workaround is to remove the attribute. Thus, if your entity includes the `"location"` attribute (with a valid `geo:point` as value) then it is localized. If your entity doesn't include the `"location"` attribute is not localized.